# Linq Query Group By Multiple Columns Having Count > 1

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a query I know how to do in SQL but struggling to figure out the LINQ query.  Here is the SQL.

```
SELECT ordNo, tranNo, COUNT(distinct custNo)
FROM orders
GROUP BY ordNo, tranNo
HAVING COUNT(distinct custNo) > 1
```

I don't feel like this is the same question that I see you marked as a duplicate. The linked question only groups on a single property.  I've lost track of the Linq queries I've tried but here is one.

```
var countList = from o in orders
            group o by new {o.orderNo, o.tranNo, o.custNo}
            into grp
            where grp.Key.custNo.Distinct().Count() > 1
            select grp;
```

I tried the suggestion below but like someone commented you can't access the custNo property.

Comment: Please share your linq too. Show what you have tried and researched. We can help from there but not write it for you..

Comment: Seems like everything is OK with your LINQ query. Do you have some error message?

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing since I don't know the table structure.

```
context.orders
    .GroupBy(o => new { o.ordNo, o.tranNo, o.custNo })
    .Where(o => o.custNo.Distinct().Count() > 1)
    .Select(o => new {
        ordNo = o.ordNo,
        tranNo = o.tranNo
    });
```

Comment: i doubt you can access custNo property like this after result of grouping